# std::make_pair automatic type deduction?

Tags: c++

Consider this function:

```
std::pair<int, double> getPair()
{
    return std::make_pair(0, 0);
}
```

**Why does this compile?**

Shouldn't `make_pair` return a `std::pair<int, int>` which is incompatible with `std::pair<int, double>`? Where is the conversion from int to double taking place?

Link to example code: https://ideone.com/Zq6ooY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::make_pair(0, 0);` indeed creates a `std::pair<int,int>` object. But, you are incorrect about incompatibility of pairs. They are compatible if their arguments are.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair):

```cpp
// #4
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr std::pair<T1,T2>( const pair<U1, U2>& p );
// #5
template< class U1, class U2 >
constexpr std::pair<T1,T2>( pair<U1, U2>&& p );
```

These are enabled if the types `TX` can be constructed from types `UX`, in your case #5 is used because `int` can be constructed from `double&&`.

Comment: ah, so the return type of std::make_pair is used to move construct the std::pair with U1, U2 as types which get converted to T1, T2. I was a little confused by the usage of T and U but now it's clear, thanks!

Comment: @Marius Yes, exactly.